# setting-up owncloud storage from scratch

Tags: owncloud

I am new to the whole linux and raspberry pi thing. I just bought a Raspberry Pi 3+ to try things out.

I have burned an image of dietpi to configure owncloud. I am lost when it comes to creating a database from scratch on an external HDD.

I watched several videos on setting up the cloud server but none are as detailed a beginner can follow. After installing dietpie i can get to the webpage of owncloud but it seems like there needs to be a database setup which is what i cannot setup.

Can anybody please provide or direct me to set this up.

Comment: Using **DietPi** as entry to linux is the hard way to learn it ;-). You may consider to use the official operating system [**Raspbian**](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/). It has many very good tutorials from the [Raspberry Pi Foundation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/).

Comment: Thanks I have the Raspbian OS and installed Nextcloud. I will go through the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about how diet pi works but there's plenty of step by step tutorials out there for owncloud and nextcloud. [Nextcloud tutorial](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-nextcloud-server/), I'd just make sure when you get to the stage where you're downloading the nextcloud/owncloud packages you get the latest release and don't just copy the release used in the article as it could be a few months or even years out of date depending on the age of the article.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to the linux OS. It does not matter which i use, i just wanted to play around with the Pi. When i saw a personal cloud i thought i would give it a try.

Comment: Definitely. It's a good one to set up because once it's running you can have as much storage as you want anywhere. Like I say I don't know how dietpi works I've never used it buts theres plenty out there in terms of the tutorials for setting it up on plain old Russian.

Comment: i was trying to install the php from the link you've shared. but i get an error

Comment: "unable to locate package 7.0"

Comment: was a typo i guess. seems to be working now.

Comment: i've managed to to move to Nextcloud and that part is done. All works well. As mentioned here (https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-nextcloud-server/) "Moving Nextcloud’s data folder", i've followed all and created a director in my 2TB external HDD, mounted it and moved the /data/ folder into the HDD. But when i try going 192.168.100.188/nextcloud it returns a white page and not the login screen.

Comment: Hi sorry it's been a while. I had the white page error but can't remember what I did to sort it. The following link should give you an idea of what it might be. https://help.nextcloud.com/t/white-page-no-login-screen/26496/3